# Importing playbooks in a rolling deploy

Tags: ansible, continuous-deployment

I am trying to automate a complex deployment. Basically:

- I upload a new version to some servers
- Run a test script
- Verify the result on each updated server
- If this succeeded, repeat on the next batch

This is currently done manually.

I have existing playbooks:

```
update.yml
start_test.sh #this one runs just locally so it does not need to be playbook
verify.yml
```

I have issues setting this up with just one playbook.
As the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html) say, it is not possible to import a playbook into the `tasks` section. Therefore, this:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  gather_facts: no  
  serial: 3

  vars:
    port: 9009

  
  tasks:
    - name: Build
      shell: ../compile.sh
      register: compile_out
      failed_when: "'OK' not in compile_out.stdout"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      run_once: true

    - name: Update batch
      import_playbook: update.yml -e "port={{ port }}"

    - name: Run test
      shell: ./start_test.sh

    - name: Verify 
      import_playbook: verify.yml
```

doesn't work.

But then, if I move the imported items to the top level, I assume the top-level `serial` parameters don't apply to all the steps, as it is only applied to the first playbook ("`Build`").

```
---
- hosts: all 
  gather_facts: no  
  serial: 3

  vars:
    port: 9009

  
  tasks:
     - name: Build
       shell: ../compile.sh
       register: compile_out
       failed_when: "'OK' not in compile_out.stdout"
       delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
       run_once: true

- name: Update batch
  import_playbook: update.yml -e "port={{ port }}"

- name: Run test
  shell: ./start_test.sh

- name: Verify 
  import_playbook: verify.yml
```

How can I apply the rolling deployment with the `serial` parameter applied to all imported playbooks?
In other words, I need to run all items to each element of the batch size (except the build which is only once, but I could live with extracting that altogether)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you see, playbook can not be include on a play, just you can include it à a top level: As a play is a full individual playbook with its own parameters like hosts and batch size.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: play1

- name: Include a play after another play
  import_playbook: otherplays.yaml


- name: This DOES NOT WORK
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: task1

    - name: This fails because I'm inside a play already
      import_playbook: stuff.yaml
```

The solution i have for you is to transform your sub playbook to roles. you can call a role inside a play and the it will be run on all the batch size. A playbook is just a collection of tasks and you can then use a role, it's also a collection of tasks.

So will have:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  gather_facts: no  
  serial: 3

  vars:
    port: 9009

  
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Build
      shell: ../compile.sh
      register: compile_out
      failed_when: "'OK' not in compile_out.stdout"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      run_once: true
  roles:
    - update
    - verify
```

And then, you execute your start_test.sh script at the end of the first role (update). Or you can also transform it at a role.

You can also use the include_tasks and then transform you sub playbook as a list of tasks to include.

Comment: I have used roles before, makes sense. Will check how easy I can move my existing playbooks to roles but this sounds good. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, can you change to solved ?

Comment: i can help you for you roles if you need